# vb.net: How to call a function, only if it is present

Tags: vb.net

I have vb.net code, which should work on device with different installed OSs. The using APIs are quite identical, except some functions that are not realized in one of OS. How can I make the code universal, without need to disable some functions in case they are not present?

Comment: How do you call these functions? Normally it doesn't even compile if the functions are not there, unless some dynamic code is added.

Comment: Show these functions

Comment: Could be a job for compiler directives, but with so few information ; hard to tell for sure

Comment: Thank you for replies, guys. The problem is exactly that the code doesn't compile if the function is not there.
Sehnsucht, tell me more please about compile directives.

Comment: Functions are quite simple. For example, SomeClass.SomeFunction() should be called, if the current OS is "Ver 6" and should not if the current OS is "Ver 7". Because if the OS is Ver 6 - SomeFunction() is present in current API and if the OS is Ver 7 is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Just got the working code. We'll use the System.Reflection:
In this way the existence of External Function will be checked only on RunTime and we can compile our code!

```
Sub DynamicLibraryUse(ByVal val As Byte) 'just because my External Function receives byte values
    Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
    myAssembly = Assembly.Load("MyExternalLibrary")

    Dim o As Object = myAssembly.CreateInstance("MyExternalNamespace.Class")
    Dim myType As Type = myAssembly.GetType("MyExternalNamespace.Class")
    Dim myMethod As MethodInfo = myType.GetMethod("MyExternalMethod")

    Dim val2 As Object() = New Object(0) {}
    val2(0) = val

    myMethod.Invoke(o, val2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Scratch what I said before, I thought #define and #if did not exist in VB.NET, but they do so:

```
#CONST SOMEOS = TRUE

Dim item As SomeClass
#IF SOMEOS
item.someFunction()
#ELSE
item.otherFunction()
#ENDIF
```

This way, if you define `SOMEOS`, only `someFunction` gets called and compiled. If you define instead `OTHEROS`, only `otherFunction` gets called and compiled.

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't work, as the code doesn't compile if someFunction() is not present in item.

Comment: True, I had forgotten the #CONST. Now it does work, just tested it :)

Comment: Thanks again. I will save your method and will try it tomorrow. For now I've found the solution :)